# Do zoom of a city in a map R tmap

Tags: r, maps, tmap

I am working with tmaps and I'm plotting Colombia's map, which has a very small city (city == "San Andrés"). When I plot the map I have this:

```
tm_shape(mapa_municipal) +
  tm_borders ()+
  tm_polygons("Ganador_20181V")
```

[image]

I have seen in some pages that it is possible to do a zoom to that part, like this:
[image]

Does anybody knows how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look of this link (https://github.com/r-tmap/tmap/issues/541)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a *mini map* or *auxuliar map*.
In tmap you can do it by creating the two maps independetly and then pasting them together with the **print()** function. You will have to add a viewport in the vp argument.

For more information check this tutorial: https://orlando-sabogal.github.io/SpatialAnalysis-MontevideoWorkshop2019/Notebooks/tmap-tutorial.nb.html#auxiliar-map

The code would look something like this:

```
MontevideoMap <- tm_shape(Montevideo) + 
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_shape(Accidents) + tm_bubbles()
UruguayMap <- tm_shape(Uruguay) + 
  tm_polygons()
library(grid)
MontevideoMap
print(UruguayMap, vp = viewport(0.17, 0.8, width = 0.25, height = 0.25))
```